# SSRS Run report on several parameters

Tags: reporting-services

I figured this would be simple, but being new to SSRS I'm not sure.

I've created a basic report template, that uses a number of data sources, to display some information about a Site. It takes a SiteId parameter

I then want to be able to run this report for multiple SiteId's to produce a report with a page for each site.

Is this possible? If so can somebody let me know how or point me to a tutorial on how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a dataset that fetches your list of sites. Then put a List area that is bound to your site list, and put a Subreport in the list. Pass the site field in as a parameter to the subreport.

Oh, and tell the List to put page breaks in.

Comment: This works, but is there anyway to bind a list to a multi value parameter instead of a dataset?